# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Studio waiting for "startup preview server listener to complete"

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-server

I'm running Worklight 6.1 DevStudio on Mac OSX 10.8 and everything was working fine over several days of development of both adapters and a hybrid application.  I rebuilt, re-deployed and ran both types of projects dozens of times with success.

The last time I tried to rebuild an adapter, it did not complete.  Usually this was completing in 10sec or so.  Eventually, after 10mins, I tried to stop it - eventually force quitting eclipse.  Now I can not get the Worklight Development Server to start. The latest thing it is waiting on is "worklight startup preview server listener to complete". Other times it will say one of the servers will not start and do I want to wait or exit.  I've had it wait up to 5 mins - I've increased the timeout. If I say exit, it hangs "forever" trying to stop the development server. I have tried:

1. Rebooting
2. Clicking "Clean Server on Next Start"
3. Forcing it down after waiting longer and longer times
4. Canceling tasks in the Progress tab in various orders etc.

Either way the best state I can get back into it is the dev studio comes up cleanly, and I can push Start, but it never completes. The Worklight Console has nothing.

The last thing in the message.log is:

> [12/30/13 9:13:44:624 PST] 0000001e
>   com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I
>   FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created:
>   "com.ibm.wsspi.channelfw.exception.ChannelException: TCP Channel
>   detected a possible loop on thread: Inbound Read Selector.1
>   com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.SocketRWChannelSelector 186" at
>   ffdc_13.12.30_09.13.44.0.log

No idea what that means.

In the trace.log I see quite a few of these:

> [12/30/13 8:50:00:281 PST] 00000015 id=
>   com.worklight.core.util.RssBrokerUtils                       1
>   getBeanFactory Failed to fetch beanFactory from ProjectLocal [project
>   ATT_WL_Banking]

Is that abnormal?

Where do I look to figure out what the development server is hung on?  At this point I am out of debug ideas and considering removing the projects one by one from the workspace and re-importing or if that fails, a re-install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote:

> ... No idea what that means.

Take a look at `/PATH-TO-WORKSPACE/WorklightServerConfig/worklight/logs`. There you will find a `ffdc` folder and in it the aforementioned log file. Edit the question with its  contents.

---

I can think of two suggested approaches/solutions here:

**suggestion #1:**

1. In Eclipse, from the Servers view, delete the "Worklight Development Server" entry
2. Quit Eclipse. Navigate to the workspace and delete the "WorklightServerConfig" folder
3. Restart Eclipse. Re-build the project.

**suggestion #2:**

1. File > Switch Workspace > Other (this will simply created a new workspace with the name you choose for it)
2. Import the project(s) from the previous workspace

I'd start with 1 and continue to 2 if 1 doesn't work for you.

Comment: Putting it in a new workspace got it going.  Then I went back and compared and noticed debugging was on in the server side.  Turning that off let the server in the original workspace start.

Comment: @MattCobb can you please provide more details concerning what you mean by "noticed debugging was on in the server side." and how to turn it off ?

Comment: I had added debug logging:  <logging traceSpecification="com.worklight.*=debug=enabled"/> to the server.xml

Comment: Why do we have to do this and how often do we do this?  I am getting the same error?  Worklight studio/Liberty/Worklight server is a bad experience for development.  Even worse than websphere for local development.  At least with my windows setup.

Comment: I am facing the same problem on mac as well with 16 GIG ram.

Answer (score 0):

Kill java process and it would help stop the startup preview listener issue on eclipse.