# Eclipse with Worklight studio and Android hangs with "The User operation is waiting for 'Startup preview server listener' to complete"

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I have been successfully developing on Eclipse Keplerwith Worklight Studio 6.1 on Windows 7 for several months now.

When suddenly I have started getting the following error message every time I try do deploy my app to the embedded worklight Server: "The User operation is waiting for 'Startup preview server listener' to complete". It hangs and never completes. See screen capture below.

I know that similar errors have been logged on StackOverflow, but I have never seen a clearcut answer for how to fix it.

Would appreciate any suggestions.

[image: Eclipse is waiting forever]

Comment: The error is that you're using Eclipse :P  I kid I kid, what choice do you have anyway when it comes to WL

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the steps described in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20844643/ibm-worklight-6-1-studio-waiting-for-startup-preview-server-listener-to-compl), it has a few steps that should address the problem.

The problem is likely to be caused by some specific configuration in your workspace so trying a new workspace should reset all settings to default, and it will also allow you to compare the different environments to identify the root cause.

Please report back to your results.